# Writing an ELO algorithm in Python for 1v1s

Tags: python, elo

I am building a simple Python script to track my friend groups ping pong rankings. I want to use the Elo ranking system from Chess, but don’t really have experience with it. Am I going about this the right way or am I missing something?

I tried the following code:

```
def calculate_elo(winner_elo, loser_elo):
    k_factor = 32
    expected_win = 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((loser_elo - winner_elo) / 400))
    winner_elo_new = winner_elo + k_factor * (1 - expected_win)
    loser_elo_new = loser_elo + k_factor * (0 - (1 - expected_win))
    return winner_elo_new, loser_elo_new
```

Everything seemed to be working, but it seems too simple. I feel like there is more to it or I am missing something.

Comment: What happens if you test it? Does it give the results you expect?